# Graphic to Visualize Quintiles Similar to Box and Whisker Plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a general question. I'm working with R and ggplot2, and I'm curious to know, do plots exist, similar to box and whisker plots for quartiles that provide information for data broken up into quintiles? If so, is it possible to code the graph using ggplot2?

Comment: Quintile plots similar to boxplots do not really exist as far as I can tell. So you'll have to make your own style. You could try make a boxplot with two horizonal centre parts (the 2nd and 3rd quintile). Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I open for suggestions and this sounds like a good option. I have some folks that are set on their data being broken up into quintiles and I'm trying to figure out how to give them something visual to represent the data with some meaningful information. Thanks for the suggestion. Any idea how I go about implementing your suggestion?

Comment: You'd have to write a function to do it manually. You'd need the functions `quantile`, `rect` and `segments`, I'd think. While you *could* do it in ggplot2, it would likely be difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `geom_boxplot` to do this.

Here is an example from `?geom_boxplot`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read Hadley Wickham and Lisa Stryjewski's [40 Years of Boxplots](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/boxplots.html).

Second, have a look at the R Graph Gallery, particularly the [Box-Percentile Plot in package Hmisc](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/RGraphGallery.php?graph=77).